# Qt Creator перестал копировать в clipboard цветной текст

Tags: qtcreator

в прошлых версиях qt creator копировал в clipboard в том, числе в html-формате, что позволяло вставлять в word и другие редакторы текст с подсветкой синтаксиса, в последней версии 11.0.2 этого нет (windows, linux).

может кто знает, какая-то настройка появилась?